# Uploading Shapefiles to Garmin?

Tags: shapefile, gps, garmin

I am trying to upload shapefile polygons onto my Garmin 60Cx GPS.  I use the Trace tool and load shapefiles via Minnesota DNR's application.  There are almost always gaps in the shapefile on the GPS, making lines and the shapefile hard to read.  Oddly enough, these gaps are often where I have not lifted the mouse/clicked anything to offset the trace tool.

Is there something that I am doing wrong?

Comment: What software are you using to create the shapefiles? If ArcGIS, try running the check geometry tool to see if it reports any errors.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately it keeps coming up without any errors.

Comment: Hmm, the only other thing I can think to try is to generalize the features--remove vertices. Perhaps try simplifying one or two polygons and see if the display is better.